# assembly - lldb can't find correct debug information on macOS

Tags: assembly, nasm, lldb

I'm learning assembly language on macOS 10.14, and my assembler nasm's version is 2.14.02, linker ld's version is ld64-409.12, debugger lldb's version is lldb-1000.11.38.2.

I have a source code file named `test.asm`, and I use

```
nasm -f macho64 -F dwarf -g test.asm
ld -e _start -o test test.o -lSystem
```

And I use lldb to debug:

```
lldb test
```

When I want to set breakpoints at certain line like:

```
(lldb)b test.asm:3
```

It turns out that:

```
error: parsing line table prologue at 0x00000000 (parsing ended around 0x00000006
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

I use

```
nm -pa test
```

to check the debug information, and it turns out:

```
0000000000000000 - 00 0000    SO xxxx(the directory)
0000000000000000 - 00 0000    SO test.asm
000000005c70cdfd - 03 0001   OSO xxxx/test.o
0000000000001f88 - 01 0000 BNSYM
0000000000001f88 - 01 0000   FUN _start
0000000000000078 - 00 0000   FUN
0000000000000078 - 01 0000 ENSYM
0000000000002000 - 02 0000 STSYM query_string
0000000000002014 - 02 0000 STSYM out_string
0000000000002025 - 03 0000 STSYM in_char
0000000000000000 - 01 0000    SO
0000000000002000 d query_string
0000000000002014 d out_string
0000000000000011 a out_string_len
0000000000000014 a query_string_len
0000000000002025 b in_char
0000000000001000 T __mh_execute_header
0000000000001f88 T _start
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

And if I use

```
dsymutil -dump-debug-map test
```

It turns out

```
---
triple:          'x86_64-apple-darwin'
binary-path:     test
objects:
  - filename:        xxxx/test.o
    timestamp:       1550896637
    symbols:
      - { sym: in_char, objAddr: 0x000000000000009D, binAddr: 0x0000000000002025, size: 0x00000000 }
      - { sym: query_string, objAddr: 0x0000000000000078, binAddr: 0x0000000000002000, size: 0x00000000 }
      - { sym: _start, objAddr: 0x0000000000000000, binAddr: 0x0000000000001F88, size: 0x00000078 }
      - { sym: out_string, objAddr: 0x000000000000008C, binAddr: 0x0000000000002014, size: 0x00000000 }
...
```

If I use `dsymutil` to pack the debug info like:

```
dsymutil test
```

And try the `lldb test` again, it turns out:

```
warning: (x86_64) xxxx/test empty dSYM file detected, dSYM was created with an executable with no debug info.
```

Comment: `test.o` is the object file, not the source file.  `test.asm` is your source file that has an interesting line 3.  But you can also debug asm just fine without source.  If lldb commands are like GDB, you can `b *0x12345678` to set a breakpoint at a numeric address, or just `b` to set a BP on the current line you single-stepped to.  (But copy/pasting an address from the disassembly window is less convenient.)  Again if it's like GDB, you can use `starti` to set a one-time breakpoint at the first instruction when starting your program.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for commenting! But even if I change into the b test.asm:3, it still turns out error. And I edit the problem to show the current error. And unfortunately, lldb doesn't have a command named "starti"

Comment: I forget if `ld -g` makes any difference.  It doesn't with `ld` from GNU binutils on Linux (where it's ignored for compatibility), but I'm wondering if the debug info is making it into the binary.

Comment: Does `b _start` work?  That should be based on simple symbols, not debug info.

Comment: @PeterCordes ld: unknown option: -g. And `b _start` still doesn't work, which turns out "Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending). WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations."

Comment: IDK then.  I don't have a Mac, and nothing else obvious stands out.  As a workaround, you could put an `int3` instruction (software breakpoint) in your nasm source code, so it's just statically there in your program.  Another thing to maybe try is leaving out the `-Fdwarf -g` options.  NASM does still emit labels into the `.o` even if you don't use `global` on them.

Comment: Are you sure you have line table information?  It does look like we went from the debug map -> the .o file since that's where the line table lives and it seems like lldb tried to parse it.  But the error you got when doing `b test.asm:3` indicates there's something fishy about the line table. Use `dwarfdump --debug-line test.o` and see what that produces.

Comment: @JimIngham I tried this and it said "empty". So where went wrong?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question.  I'm not very familiar with nasm.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this?

Comment: @sheeldotme No… Sad;(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I worked out. LLDB supports program assembled by GAS with source code using AT&T syntax. And if you really want to debug program assembled by NASM with source code using intel syntax on macOS, just use GDB.